# There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400). Required String parameter 'name' is not present

Tags: java

User can search something on my list

```html
 <form action="/worldoffragrance">
        <input name="search"/>
        <input type="submit" value="search"/>
```

If list its empty, I'd like to make another website, where User can put what he want  , How can i resolve this problem? :)

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String fragrance() { return "fragrance"; }


@RequestMapping("/worldoffragrance")
public String worldoffragrance(
        @RequestParam(value = "search") String search,
        @RequestParam(value = "operation", required = false, defaultValue = "search") String operation, Model model) {
    List<Fragrance> matchingPerfumes = advisor.findMatchingPerfume(search);
    if (matchingPerfumes.isEmpty()) {
        return "redirect:/fragrancenotfound";
    }
    model.addAttribute("matchingPerfumes", matchingPerfumes);
    return "result";
}

@RequestMapping("/fragrancenotfound")
public String fragranceNotFound(
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String getName,
        @RequestParam(value = "ingredients", required = true) String getIngredients,
        @RequestParam(value = "operation", required = false, defaultValue = "add" ) String operation, ModelMap model)
 {
     model.addAttribute("getName", "getIngredients");
    return "redirect: /createNewFragrance";
}

@RequestMapping("/createnewfragrance")
public String createnewfragrance() {
    return "createNewFragrance";}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are redirecting to `/fragrancenotfound` which has a required parameter of `name` (and `ingredient`) which you are not providing. either provide these values or make them not required